Identify an actress from TV
Here's what I know.
She was on an episode of Law and Order: SVU. 
In the episode, there were young girls being manipulated into sexual relations with a man whom they believed was their biological father (through sperm donation/insemination.)
The woman I am looking for was the current wife of the Dr. (the man) who was being accused of the manipulation and the sperm donor.
All I can remember about the woman: English accent of some kind. Reminds me of Rhona Mitra, but Rhona doesn't have any SVU episodes listed in her IMDB filmography.

Feel free to edit the title or body as needed, please.

Given the very unique plot you describe and your apparently good memory of it, identifying the actual episode it was would be a good start. After that determining the actress should be quite trivial with the help of the appropriate references. Did you watch the episode recently? Can you classify its position inside the whole timeline of the show to some degree? Identifying the structure of detective team might also help to put it into the timeline, since there have been some cast changes thoughout the show.

OK, so that was embarrasing. After actually spending the time to Google the answer I found it in under two minutes. Sorry about that. 
Episode was Father Dearest, talked about in this Wikipedia entry.
The actor's name is Sonya Walger.

Eric Close played the accused.
James Van Der Beek was the actual bad guy.

"But I don't wahnt yore lahf!"

There is nothing wrong with answering your own question. Make sure to mark it as answered though. Good details in the answer.
